# Laravel 8 - Changing database connection for model

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 8 and would like to query a model from my production database.

I tried the following:

```
DB::connection('mysql_prod')->Company::where('symbol', $symbol)
            ->first();
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$Company
```

I would like to get a laravel model - in this case `Company` - back.

Any suggestions how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use on if you are changing for one query.

```
 Company::on('mysql_prod')->where('symbol', $symbol)->first();
```

define `$connection` property in `Company` model  so no need to mention connection

```
protected $connection = 'mysql_prod';
```

so query is

```
Company::where('symbol', $symbol)->first();
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#database-connections

Comment: Thx for your reply! I would like to define the connection property locally as I only want to change the connection in this 1 function.

Comment: @Carol.Kar use on  Company::on('mysql_prod')->where('symbol', $symbol)->first();

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Company::on('mysql_prod')->where('symbol', $symbol)
            ->first();
```